# Why can I pass a double for a float argument in a function

Tags: c++, function, floating-point, arguments, double

The following code compiles and executed without any issues.
I would have the compiler (GCC 9.2.0) expected to prevent me from this, but it doesn't.
Can anyone point out the background of this effect to me?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

const double c = 1.23456789;

void print(float f)
{
    std::cout << (f == c) << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    double d=1.23456789;
    print(d);
    std::cout << (d == c) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output (making clear that some implicit cast took place)

```
0
1
```

Comment: Side note: If you crank up the warning level (or turn it on explicitly) you can get a warning from most compilers about implicit conversions. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/39sddjfz8

Comment: You can read all about _implicit conversions_ [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion).  Specifically, [floating point conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating-point_conversions).

Comment: @DrewDormann thanks. My example is mentioned as `numeric conversion`, I guess.

Comment: @user4581301 you should write this as an answer. Adding `-Wconversion` to my compiler flags made clear very quickly, why this is not active by default.

Comment: It's not a default because in many programs you would get a storm of conversion warnings that no one cares about the vast majority of the time. I usually just turn it on for safety critical code.

Comment: You can disallow the conversion by adding `template <typename T> void print(T);` which will cause a link error.  Or `template <typename T> void print(T) { static_assert(false, "you cannot print that"); }` for more immediate feedback.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can I pass a double for a flaot argument in a function

Because you're allowed to pass an argument as a parameter of different type into a function if there is an implicit conversion sequence from the argument type to the parameter type. Conversion from `double` to `float` is such implicit conversion.

> I would have the compiler (GCC 9.2.0) expected to prevent me from this

The compiler wouldn't conform to the language if it prevented from compiling well-formed programs. You can ask the compiler to warn you in this case. The option to enable such warning in your compiler is `-Wfloat-conversion`